# How to get PYTHONHOME for a specific interpreter?

Tags: python, python-embedding

I am trying to enumerate available Python interpreters, and I need their home paths so that I could load the pythonXXX dynamic library.

I can find the executables no problem by listing directories in PATH. However, I can't find how to get the default PYTHONHOME for the newfound executable. It is not set outside, so `os.environ['PYTHONHOME']` throws `KeyError`.

There's `Py_GetPythonHome` in embedding API, but to get there, I first need to load the dynamic library.

Is there a way to get what `Py_GetPythonHome` returns from the interpreter itself?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the default PYTHONHOME is empty. This is what Python does when it's empty:

1. Starting with the directory where the Python executable resides, append `lib/pythonXX/` where XX is the version number and check if it contains `os.py`. If it does, then that is the "prefix" directory. Otherwise, go up one directory and repeat the procedure.
2. If it went all the way to root `/` and still hasn't found the prefix directory, it will check the prefix directory that was set when it was built. Unfortunately, this is hardcoded into interpreter.

If you can afford to execute the interpreter to get its stdout, then you can try running `python -m site`.